# Regex in emacs to change all numbers like .x to 0.x

Tags: regex, emacs

I am new to emacs and I am learning emacs!

I have a text file which contains lots of floating point numbers in random fashion.

Some numbers are stored like `0.9, 0.184 0.56` etc. While some numbers are stored like `.9, .184, .56` etc..

I want a **regular expression in emacs** which can **convert all** `.xxxx` **numbers to** `0.xxxx` how can I achieve this?

*Maximum number of digits after floating point is 4(If it matters)*

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be necessarily better than @nullptr's answer (atleast for this particular example), but you can also use the following regexp with `query-replace-regexp` bound to <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>

```
\(^\|[^0-9]+\)\.\([[:digit:]]+\)
```

The above regexp uses [character classes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes). `[:digit:]` matches any digit. Then you can replace it with

```
\10.\2
```

You may have noticied that emacs syntax for regular expressions is a bit different that the regexp syntax you may familiar with in other languages eg. `(` and `|` need to escaped in emacs regexp. You may find the following useful for learning about emacs regexp

1) You can read the documentation of `query-replace-regexp` by doing `C-h f query-replace-regexp RET`

2) [This emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) has a good summary about the emacs regexp syntax.

3) The [elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) has more in depth explanation of the regexp syntax.

There are a couple of packages you can use to learn about emacs regexp

1) Vanilla emacs comes with `re-builder`, do `M-x re-builder` this will open a small window at the bottom where you can enter a regexp and it will highlight the regexp matches in the buffer.

2) I personally find the package `visual-regexp.el` ([link](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el)) very useful when working with emacs regexp, it basically gives you a 'live feedback' of regexp matches (including group matches) when doing regexp replaces. Here are a couple of screenshots demonstrating the use of the command `vr/query-replace` provided by the package

[image]

And then when replacing the regexp it displays what part is going to be replaced by what

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work if the number is at the begining of the string.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I will modify the regexp

Comment: It' ok, but I'd test start of line or any character but digit before the dot, not only space like in `.56;.2-.456`. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: Thank you Iqbal for the answer and also for the `visual-regexp.el` it is really great!

Comment: I really appreciate this package, I had problem with emacs' regex and now things can be clear, specially grouping and watching if there are any edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is just to use the built in `query-replace-regexp` capability (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>). Something like the following should get you started.

Query replace regexp: `\([^0-9]\)\(\.[0-9]+\)`
Query replace regexp \([^0-9]\)\(\.[0-9]+\) with: `\10\2`

Comment: It doesn't work if the number is at the begining of the string.